# NodeJS, get the names of a dir

Tags: mysql, node.js, csv

I am quite new to NodeJS, so any help will be welcome!

I can read all files inside a dir. It shows me all the file names and extension. All of the files are *.csv.

Like so:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var junk = require('junk');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

const diretorio = 'download';
const nomeArquivo = diretorio

let dirBuf = Buffer.from(diretorio);

let arquivos = fs.readdirSync(diretorio);
    console.log(arquivos.filter(junk.not));
    arquivos.filter(junk.not).forEach(file => {
        var conteudo = fs.readFile(dirBuf, 'utf8', function(){  
        });
  });
```

Now, i want to open each file on a loop to insert the data into mysql:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(diretorio + "/Notify_273_exp_complete_2018-01-18 19.15.25.csv");

csv
 .fromStream(stream, {headers : false},{ignoreEmpty: true})
 .on("data", function(data){
     console.log(data);
 })
 .on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");
 });
```

So, I can read all the files on a dir and read the content but not the same time.
What I need to do is:

Put the name of file into a var:

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream(diretorio + filename);
```

So the script reads all files and then insert the content into a table. The connection with MySQL I did with:

```
// CONECTION WITH MYSQL
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con = mysql.createConnection({
  host: "localhost",
  user: "*****",
  password: "******",
  database: "*******"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
});
// END CONNECTION
```

Finally. It's my logic correct? There is another way to do that?
Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 0):

This guy saved my life with this:
https://code-maven.com/list-content-of-directory-with-nodejs

```
var fs = require('fs');
var junk = require('junk');
var csv = require('fast-csv');

const diretorio = 'download';
const nomeArquivo = diretorio

fs.readdir(nomeArquivo, function(err, items) {
    // console.log(items.filter(junk.not));

    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
        nome = items[i];
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(diretorio + '/' + nome);
    csv
     .fromStream(stream, {headers : false},{ignoreEmpty: true})
     .on("data", function(data){
         console.log(data);
     })
     .on("end", function(){
         console.log("done");
     });
    }
});
```

Runs like a breeze on the Terminal!
Now just need to save the data to the data table!